# How to use toSorted() method in typescript

Tags: typescript, sorting

When I try to use the **toSorted** method in typescript like this:

```
const x = [1,2];
const y = x.toSorted();
```

I got this ts error:

> Property 'toSorted' does not exist on type 'number[]'.ts(2339)

this also happen with **toReverse**() and **toSplice**() methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

toSorted is a new feature Array.prototype.toSorted() and it exists in ES2023 https://www.sonarsource.com/blog/es2023-new-array-copying-methods-javascript/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted#browser_compatibility

This feature are really fresh and it is not supported each browser and code editor. Here you can find an example(JS) https://playcode.io/1521165
or you can use the latest version of TS(today 5.2.0-dev.20230701)

You can use methods of TypedArray with Array object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray

```
const x = new Uint8Array([1,2]);
const y = x.toSorted();
```

Or you can use a standard sort method

```
const numbersArray = [45, 2, 6, 207];
numbersArray.sort((a: number, b: number) => {
  return a - b;
});
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-d4dfdn?file=index.ts

Comment: Even when I used this method, I faced the same problem:
Property 'toSorted' does not exist on type 'Uint8Array'.ts(2339)
anyway, thank u for your time

and for your example, the sort() method returns the reference to the same array,
so now, both of numbersArray and numersArraySorted are the same (both are sorted)

Comment: I've corrected my answer and demo a little :)

Comment: Careful, in example you've assigned reference to the sorted result, but the `sort` is in fact "in place", so the original array is sorted too. That's the main difference between the `sort` and `toSorted`, and your example seems to be a little bit misleading, so I just want to point it out.

Answer (score 19):

To resolve this, you'll want to update your `tsconfig.json` file.

Find the `compilerOptions` section and make sure the `compilerOptions` value includes `ESNext.Array`. It should look something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ESNext.Array", "DOM", "ESNext", "etc..."]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Find your tsconfig file and add "ES2023.Array" to "lib" value. I got a similar issue today (for "toSpliced") and solution works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Works well, it's also better than the top answer which uses ESNext, which can make it brittle.

Comment: This answer is helpful. But it would be nice to include how to find the answer in docs? For example, what other values are available under the ES2023.* namespace, and how can I find them?

After searching, I found that these are defined in the TS source here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/src/lib

Answer (score 4):

Update your project's TypeScript to version higher than 5.2
(e.g. yarn add typescript@lastest)

Optionally you can try adding into tsconfig.ts file "lib": [**"ESNext.Array"**, "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, because my TS version was not up-to-date. Since updating the TS version was no solution for me at the moment, I used a workaround.
For anyone else who is looking for the functionality of toReversed() (or similar new Array functions) without a TS-version update, the below might help.

I used the spread syntax to get a reversed copy of my array:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]

const reversedArray = [...array].reverse()

console.log(reversedArray)
// [ 4, 3, 2, 1 ]

console.log(array)
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

[This website](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-reverse-an-array-in-javascript-js-reverse-function/) was my source, it includes more ways to sort (and copy) arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Updating Node version fixed this for me.  `toSorted` is only available from Node 20+.

`nvm install 21`

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted