# How can I use ES2023 methods in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to use the ES2023 `toReversed()` method on TypeScript, but I'm getting this error when I'm building my Next.js project:

> Type error: Property 'toReversed' does not exist on type 'Job[]'. Did you mean 'reverse'?

I tried updating TypeScript to newest version and adding `"ES2023"` and `"ES2023.Array"` into `lib` in `tsconfig.json` but it didn't work.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext", "ES2023", "ES2023.Array"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "components/Home/about.tsx", "components/Socials/Icons/socialIcons.tsx", "components/Socials/socials.tsx", "pages/_app.tsx", "functions/formatDate.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I already saw [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593892/how-to-use-tosorted-method-in-typescript), but he did not add `"ES2023"` and `"ES2023.Array"` into his `tsconfig.json` file, and I don't know why I'm still getting this error even though I updated my `tsconfig.json` file.

Why do I keep getting this error with ES2023 configurations in my `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Good point, looks like TS hasn't updated to includes those new methods into its Array type

Comment: @tmhao2005 Yes, although it does have ES2023 and ES2023.Array in its source code in GitHub.

Comment: The gist of it: `toSorted()` and some others are coming in 5.2, which you can access in dev/RC builds at the moment, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54298

Comment: @tevemadar I saw this question before posting, and at the time of the post, these methods were not supported by all browsers, but now they are, so I thought maybe there is a solution right now, and thank you for telling me about the 5.2 version (I'm currently on the 5.1.6 version).

Comment: The only time I had to "hack in" something what I knew existing, but the compiler did not know about, was `OffscreenCanvas` once. But as it's a global, a simple `declare var OffscreenCanvas: any;` solved it. I have no idea how to do that for a method.

Comment: @PeterB Hi, thanks a lot for your review, I didn't like the way it was before and I thought users couldn't see the error that well, but your points are clear I will reconsider it and change it ASAP, again thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Since typescript 5.2 is now available having "ES2023" or "ES2023.Array" in the "lib" property of your tsconfig.json should now work.

Comment: Hm I'm on TS `5.2.2` and get red squiggly lines below `ES2023` 

Comment: @CanRau Where do you get the error, when compiling or in VSCode?

Comment: think it was vscode but I've (or it) resolved it somehow since then